# Segue to View that's a part of AddressBookUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, addressbookui

I have my Storyboard set up in my Xcode project, I have created a new `ABPersonViewController` and set the segue to it.

[image: Image 1]

However, I'm running into a problem that when I make the segue, the view is completely black:

[image: Image 2]

I understand there may be solutions with wrapper classes, which is not what I'm looking for; I feel as though there must be some supported way to do this.

Is there a way to segue to "predefined" view controllers from frameworks like `AddressBookUI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ABPersonViewController, you instantiate it, set its `displayedPerson` and `personViewDelegate`, and push it onto an existing navigation controller's stack. Here's working downloadable example code from my book:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.m